# Find path/namespace of JToken in a Newtonsoft JObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, path, json.net

I have the following code example (C# using Newtonsoft Json.NET) that serializes a Json string into a JObject:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("{\"F01\" : \"f01\", " +
                    "\"F02\" : \"f02\", " +
                    "\"L01\" : [" +
                        "{" +
                            "\"L01F01\" : \"l01f01\", " +
                            "\"L01F02\" : \"l01f02\"" +
                        "}, " +
                        "{" +
                            "\"L01F01\" : \"l01f01\", " +
                            "\"L01F02\" : \"l01f02\"" +
                        "}, " +
                        "{" +
                            "\"L01F03\" : \"l01f03\" " +
                        "}, " +
                        "{" +
                            "\"L01F03\" : \"l01f03\", " +
                            "\"L01L02\" : [" +
                                "{" +
                                    "\"L01L02F01\" : \"l01l02f01\"" +
                                "}" +
                            "]" +
                        "}" +
                    "]" +
                    "}");
```

*Notice that the JSON has a dynamic structure where not all items in arrays has same names and attributes.*

And I make the following JTokens:

```
var test01 = obj["F01"];
var test02 = obj["L01"][0]["L01F01"];
var test03 = obj["L01"][3]["L01L02"][0]["L01L02F01"];
```

I would like to know if somebody know any way to obtain the "path" of the test variables in this a way similar to:

```
GetPathOf(test01) => "F01"
GetPathOf(test02) => "L01[0].L01F01"
GetPathOf(test03) => "L01[3].L01L02[0].L01L02F01"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A [`Path`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) property was added to [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) in [release 5.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/5.0.1) (April 7, 2013) which does exactly what you describe.

So in your example you could simply write:

```
string path03 = test03.Path;
```

The `path03` variable would then contain `L01[3].L01L02[0].L01L02F01`.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Dhc4i

Comment: The opposite method to get a nested JToken by passing a Path to a JToken is to use myJToken.SelectObject(myPath). [click](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm). There are also some overloads.